# Variable arguments function, passing values to another function

Tags: c++, c

I have a function with some variable arguments params, and I need to call inside it another function passing this arguments. 
For example, someone call this function:

```
bool A(const char* format, ...)
{
  //some work here...
  bool res = B(format, /*other params*/);
  return res;
}

bool B(const char* format, /**/, ...)
{
   va_list arg;
   va_start(arg, format);
   //other work here...
}
```

I need to know, how to pass the variable params by the ellipse received by A to B function. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do that directly, so you need to follow the same pattern that C library follows with `fprintf` / `vfprintf` groups of functions.

The idea is to put the implementation into the `v`-prefixed function, and use the user-facing function with no `v` prefix to "unwrap" the `va_list` before calling the real implementation.

```
bool A(const char* format, ...)
{
  //some work here...
   va_list arg;
   va_start(arg, format);
   bool res = vB(format, arg);
   va_end(arg);
   return res;
}

bool B(const char* format, /**/, ...)
{
   va_list arg;
   va_start(arg, format);
   bool res = vB(format, arg);
   va_end(arg);
   return res;
}

bool vB(const char* format, va_list arg) {
    // real work here...
}
```

Comment: GCC has an extension doing that though.

Comment: @Deduplicator It is best to program to the language free of extensions for maximum portability.

Comment: I concurr, just mentioning it for completeness.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to pass them in the usual notation the only thing that is possible is to forward variable arguments to a function that accepts a `va_list`. Example for forwarding arguments to `vprintf` (the `va_list` version of `printf`):

```
int printf(const char * restrict format, ...) {
  va_list arg;
  va_start(arg, format);
  int ret = vprintf(format, arg);
  va_end(args);
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: So, there is not possible way, just doing another function...

Answer (score 2):

There you go:

```
bool A(const char* format,...)
{
    bool res;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args,format);
    res = B(format,args);
    va_end(args);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: in that case, `B()` must be `bool B( const char *, va_list );` instead of `bool B( const char *, ... );`

Comment: @Ingo Leonhardt: So according to what you're saying, `printf` also takes `const char *, va_list` instead of `const char *, ...`, which is not correct to the best of my knowledge. Are you sure about this?

Comment: yout couldn't (portably) call `printf()` like that, but you had to use `vprintf()` instead, which indeed is `int vprintf( const char *, va_list );`. Look at @Sergey L.'s answer